# Как зафиксировать ширину колонки в bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap4

Есть вот такой макет

```
<div className='container app'>
<div className="row align-items-center justify-content-center content">
  <div className="col-7 col-content">
    <div className="row top-panel">
      <div className="col-8 left"></div>
      <div className="col right"></div>
    </div>
    <div className="row main">
      <div className="col-7 left"></div>
      <div className="col right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Это учебный проект будущего SPA приложения. Как сделать так, чтобы ширина колонки col-content оставалась одинаковой при любых размера экрана( при маленьких размерах появлялась полоса прокрутки)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

уберите из класса `col-7`

Добавьте `width:750px;` (нужную вам ширину) к классу `col-content` и `overflow-x:auto;` к `content`.

Ещё можно не убирать `col-7`, тогда добавить `min-width:750px` (запретить становиться элементу меньше чем 750px) и опять же добавить `overflow` как описано выше.

Сделал пример кода. Не понимаю почему в вашей разметке `className` вместо нормального `class`, подозреваю что это какой-то фреймворк для мобильника по типу ionic.

```css
.content {
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.col-content {
  min-width: 750px;
  background:#c3fffc;
  padding:30px 0px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.left{    background: #e8c3ff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
.right{
  background:#ddffc3;
  border:1px solid #000;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='container app'>
  <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center content">
    <div class="col-7 col-content">
    col-content
      <div class="row top-panel">
        <div class="col-8 left">left</div>
        <div class="col right">right</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row main">
        <div class="col-7 left">left (main)</div>
        <div class="col right">right (main)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я пробовал использовать свойство min-width и что то не пошло, подскажите пожалуйста, а почему вы ширину 750px берете, это какое то специальное значение? 

P.S. Это фреймворк react, поэтому там className.

Comment: @EgorG нет, просто для примера. Вы же сказали фиксированная ширина, вот и зафиксировал на 750. Можете ставить любое нужное вам в пикселях, процентах, wv и т.д.